# Cannot find module '../build/Release/opencv4nodejs

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and node js, trying to learn OpenCV in node js.

I came across [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs) which I found best for learning.

I have followed all steps to install OpenCV and setting environment variables for OpenCV and done `npm install opencv4nodejs` also. able to run Quick start code given but when I try to run example machineLearningOCR.js from examples folder I get error `Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/opencv4nodejs'`

I run command `node machineLearningOCR.js` from cmd but getting error mentioned above on line `const cv = require('../');`

How to run examples given in opencv4nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cloned the repository and want to use the examples directly from the examples folder then you have to `npm install` in the root directory first to build the module.

Optionally you can `npm install opencv4nodejs` in any project directory, copy the examples into that directory and replace `const cv = require('../');` with `const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');`.

You can also directly submit an issue here: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues

Comment: Thanks!!! sorry for the basic problems, can I ask you one more question?I am trying to learn your example machineLearningOCR.js for implementing 7-segment display OCR can you tell me am I on right path@justadudewhohacks

Comment: The example learns to classify hand written letters using HOG descriptors and an SVM as classifier. I am not quite sure if it is necessary to use machine learning for 7-segment display, I think this can even be done with simpler image analysis, but might also depend on the requirements of your application. But you can definitely try to do it with HOG and SVM, that should work.

Comment: I cloned your repo, cd into it, and trying to npm i. But getting error "RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stderr maxBuffer length exceeded".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I did solve the issue with the following steps.

First all of. I checked the npm version, for this case I recommend you updated or pass your software resources at the next version.

[NodeJs 14.16.0](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/)

**NodeJs version: 14.16.0**.   You can verify the version with this command if you had another NodeJs version installed

```
node --version
```

**Npm version: 6.4.11** You need verify if you had this version installed only you will able to validate this if you have NodeJs but if you didn't have node you can install the version I recommend you

```
npm --version
```

After you set the NodeJs and npm versions you need to verify the following things

- Have visual studio 2015 or latest with the development for desktop component
- Have cmake program installed
- Have git bash
- Have Java or the language you will to work
- Have the environment variables for the above programs I mentioned

Then you can try again to install open Cv

You need to reopen another or new terminal and then you will execute this command

```
npm install --save openc4nodejs
```

And then

```
npm install -g openc4nodejs
```

After than or before don't forget to install appium  I recommend you 1.19.1 version

You can verify if you have appium with opencv with open Cv doctor you can run `appium-doctor` and check if the Open cv component are present.

For to install appium doctor you can run this command, `npm install -g appium-doctor`

I hope this answers will be helpful for you

Autor: Eder Carbonero

Comment: opencv4nodejs is spelled incorrectly. Should be `npm install --save opencv4nodejs` with a 'v'